# Data types when reading mysql with python library MySqldb

Tags: python, mysql

I wish to extract data from a mysql table, and write it verbatim to a text file. The most simplified form of my code is below, of course it must be much refined later (both the SELECT statement and further conditions in the python code); but I already run into trouble here.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="--------",
                     user="-----",
                     passwd="xyz",
                     db="abc123")
cur = db.cursor()

outfil='..........'
f=open(outfil,"w")
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM aerodrome ORDER BY sequence")
row=[""]
for row in cur.fetchall():
 print(row)
 f.write(",".join(row))
f.close()
db.close()
```

When run, the row looks like

```
(1L, 'UK', '', '', '', ' Abbots Bromley', '', '', '', Decimal('52.8277800'),
```

with the type indicators ("L" in the first field, "Decimal" in the last) clobbering up. How can I force obtaining just the actual data, without those type indicators?

Comment: I think, the best way is to convert data type before write data to the stream

Comment: You could come up with something a bit hacky, like a regex to remove all non decimal characters (`'/[^0-9]/'`) and a list of values to be replaced by nothing (`Decimal(` for instance), but this would require you knowing in advance what each row's type is and what you need to addapt to get the raw data. I expect what you want is to get the raw data directly for you mysql connector no ?
If you want to go the hacky route I'd love to help!

Comment: Thanks Olivier, I prefer simple approaches :) so I  should like to never get the "Decimal" and such more, rather than getting them and then having to remove them. And yes, you have correctly understood that I want to get the raw data for the database, clean and unadorned.

Comment: Okay, makes perfect sense. I Googled the question previously but didn't find anything useful. I don't usually use `mysql` or the `MySQLdb` connector, so I'm afraid I can't be of much help here. Good luck with this!

Comment: I wonder if the crux of my issue might be that the fetchall() returns a tuple, whereas I expect/want/require a list. Or?